# Oracle SQL - How to retrieve the ID Count difference between today vs yesterday

Tags: sql, oracle, date, difference

I have a table that captures when a customer purchases a product. It captures a unique purchase id along with a timestamp of when the purchase was made.

I want to be able to query, the difference between how many purchases were taken today vs yesterday?

Not sure how to query this on oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when trunc(datecol) = trunc(sysdate - 1) then 1 else 0 end) as num_yesterday,
       sum(case when trunc(datecol) = trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as num_today,
       sum(case when trunc(datecol) = trunc(sysdate) then 1
                when trunc(datecol) = trunc(sysdate - 1) then -1
           end) as diff
from t
where datecol >= trunc(sysdate - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Group function to grouping the purchase day with timestamp information and count the purchase id.

```
select trunc(purchase_ts) Day, count(purchase_id) Count
from purchase
group by trunc(purchase_ts)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRUNC` on the column will prevent Oracle from using an index on that column (instead you would need a separate function-based index); instead use a `CASE` statement to test whether the date is between the start of the day and the start of the next day and then `COUNT` the values between those ranges:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY <= your_date_column
         AND  your_date_coumn < TRUNC( SYSDATE )
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS count_for_yesterday,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) <= your_date_column
         AND  your_date_coumn < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS count_for_today
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY <= your_date_column
AND    your_date_coumn < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```